# Python: Getting all letters/symbols at the end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I tried writing a RegEx in Python, which divides a string into two parts, the string itself and the dots at the end of it, so that "test..." would be -> ["test", "..."]

I tried:

```
regex_end = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z0-9.',_&%+\s-]+)(\.{3,5})$")
```

and it worked fine when the string only ended with 3 dots.
A string with 5 dots like "test....." results in ["test..", "..."]

How can I get all the dots?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a non-greedy match, try: `regex_end = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z0-9.',_&%+\s-]+?)(.{3,5})$")`.

Comment: `[^\.]+` is much simpler for the first regex, and it would solve this problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon: but `.` is in the first half as well, so presumably OP wants to be able to match `hello.there...` correctly (i.e., only the final stops).

Comment: Ahh, good catch.  I did not see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-greedy match for the first half and a greedy (default) match for the second half:

```py
import re

regex_end = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z0-9.',_&%+\s-]+?)(\.*)$")

test = ["test", "test.", "test...", "test....", "t...est. ..."]

for t in test:
    print (re.findall(regex_end, t))
```

results in correct looking results

```
[('test', '')]
[('test', '.')]
[('test', '...')]
[('test', '....')]
[('t...est. ', '...')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't think about non-greedy matches

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import re

text = ['test.....', 'test...', '..test.....', 'test', '...']

for t in text:
    result = re.search('(.*?)(\.+$)', t)
    if result:
        print(result.group(1, 2))
"""
('test', '.....')
('test', '...')
('..test', '.....')
('', '...')
"""
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Johann ! If this answer worked for you, please consider marking it as "Accepted".